# Entry Widget Justification - text longer than widget

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have an entry widget with a width of 60 chars. The widget is right justified. When the textvariable associated with the entry widget contains less than 60 chars, the entry widget shows the text right justified. When the textvariable is longer than 60 characters the text is left justified. I cannot insert the text from a position before the start, i.e. -34, so is this impossible to achieve?

I want to be able to display the end of the text if it's longer than the entry widget.

```
self.infile_var = tk.StringVar()
self.infile_e = tk.Entry(self.infile_lf,
                         textvariable=self.infile_var,
                         justify='right',
                         bd =2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand your desire to insert at a position before the start -- that doesn't make any sense. However, if all you want is for the right-most characters to be visible you can use the [xview_moveto](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.xview_moveto-method) method.

```
self.infile_e.xview_moveto(1.0)
```

Comment: The character string a file path, but the leading parts are 'inconsequential' as far as the user is concerned. What the user needs to see is the file name. However for completeness I want them to be able to see the complete file path, hence needing all the path in the entry widget, but the end of it displayed 'first'.
Thanks for the reply, I will try it.