# Tkinter entry text justification after insert

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

Using Python 2.6.1 or 2.7.9 Tkinter's Entry widget entry.insert seems to destroy left justification. How do I get the text to stay left justified?  Specifically, after entry.get() provides what I type into the widget, I insert additional text automatically at the beginning and redisplay it.  When redisplayed, the justification ~sometime~ changes.

Specifically, when I enter a string of 20 characters or less and the entry.insert makes it longer, all works okay with some of the string not visible off the right side of the entry widget. When I enter a string of 21 characters or more and the entry.insert makes it longer, it displays
as right justified so only the end of the string is visible and "THANK YOU" is never seen off the left side.

Why does this happen and how do I get it to stop?  I've considered [Entry Widget Justification - text longer than widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281302/entry-widget-justification-text-longer-than-widget) but in his case, the OP wasn't doing an insert and the vague question didn't get a good answer.

The default displayed text size for an Enter widget is 20 characters, but the same phenomena happens for whatever Entry width I specify.  Phenomena also happens on Raspberry Pi 3 and Mac OSX.

```
# demo of broken justification 1/14/2017
import Tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()

def clear_entry():
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry.config(bg='white')

def process_butninput():
    if entry.get()=="done":
        master.destroy()
    else:
        entry.insert(0,"THANK YOU ")
        datarecord = entry.get()
        print( "%s" % datarecord) # debugging only
        entry.config(bg='green')
        entry.after(1500, clear_entry)

label = tk.Label( master, text="Enter text: ")
label.grid(row=0, padx=20, pady=30)
entry = tk.Entry( master)
entry.grid( row=0, column=1)
button = tk.Button( master, text='Enter', command=process_butninput)
button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=30)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe move cursor to the left `entry.icursor(0)`. Cursor is always visible so if it is at the end then text can be right justified.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I added your statement just before turning the background green.   Problem remains.  // That said, your observation is interesting if "cursor is always visible", what if this conflicts with the justification.  That does seem like a conflict.

Comment: More info from increasing the delay to 10 seconds (so I can play with the cursor while the field is green):    During the "after" delay, the cursor starts off the left side of the text.  In other words it's not visible.  But as soon as I use left or right arrow, the text immediately left justifies and I can see and use the cursor.  Problem still remains.

Comment: Not fixed.  But I have a work-around.  I have to totally delete the text and insert all the new text at one time in the "else:" paragraph.  Simply inserting "THANK YOU" still does not work.  I'm still interested why the partial insert breaks the text justify.   I don't know how to show code blocks in a comment, so here is the change in-line:     `datarecord = entry.get()
 datarecord = "THANK YOU" + datarecord
 entry.delete( 0, tk.END)
 entry.insert( 0, datarecord)`

Comment: So now you can put this workaround as answer - it can be usefull for others.

Comment: I don't like my own work around, so I echoed Bryan's answer in a way that might help someone else understand.

Answer (score 1):

Text justify is only relevant for under-sized text strings.  If the text string is longer than the Entry width, then justify does nothing and you have to use xview.

I was basing my expectations on how, for example, Word and Excel display justified text, but that is not how Tkinter displays text in the Entry widget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are asking, but it sounds like you simply need to scroll the contents of the entry widget after inserting "THANK YOU " so that the character at position 0 (zero) is visible.

```
entry.insert(0,"THANK YOU ")
entry.xview(0)
```